# What is the reason for the unexpected position change after toggle()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Expected behavior: click button and toggle the display of div#colorBox1 slightly below and to the right of the button.

Experienced behavior: on first click of button the display of the div functions as expected. however, the second toggling the div appearance, without refreshing the page, the div appears further to the right, and further down than on the first time toggling appearance.

from then on, every time appearance is toggled the div remains in this second, lower, further-to-the-right position.

side-note: after refreshing the page, the first toggled appearance, the div position will be correct.

JS:

```
function toggleColorPicker(element) {
  let id,
    target,
    coordinates,
    newLeft,
    newTop;

  id = $(element).attr('id');
  target = `#colorBox${id}`;

  coordinates = $(element).offset();
  newLeft = coordinates.left + 25;
  newTop = coordinates.top + 25;

  $(target).offset({ top: newTop, left: newLeft });

  $(target).toggle();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <button onclick="toggleColorPicker(this);" type="button" id="1"></button>
  <div
    id="colorBox1"
    style="height:300px; width: 300px; background-color: black; position: absolute; display:none;"
  >
    <label for="promptTextColor">
      <input
        style="display:none;"
        class="form-control"
        name="promptTextColor"
        id="promptTextColor"
        type="text"
      />

      <canvas id="colorCanvas1" class="color-canvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is a codepen demonstrating this behavior: https://codepen.io/vorousjames/pen/omvxry?editors=1010

What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `$( target ).toggle();` above `coordinates = $( element ).offset();` like this

```
function toggleColorPicker ( element ) {

    var id, target, coordinates, newLeft, newTop;

    id = $( element ).attr( 'id' );
    target = "#colorBox" + id;
    $( target ).toggle();
    // position target relative to button pressed
    coordinates = $( element ).offset();
    newLeft = coordinates.left + 25;
    newTop = coordinates.top + 25;
    $( target ).offset( { top: newTop, left: newLeft } );


}
```

You probably want to do offset calculations after the element state is known, either hidden or displayed, then compute  the calculations. I suggest you to learn about the fundamentals of why this had possibly occurred in the future.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction

Answer (score 0):

`$( target ).offset( { top: newTop, left: newLeft } )` is not resetting properly.

You can try :

```
$( target ).css( { top: newTop, left: newLeft } )
```

for the desired output.

-Help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleColorPicker(element) {
        var id, target, coordinates, newLeft, newTop;

        id = $(element).attr('id');
        target = "#colorBox" + id;

        coordinates = $(element).offset();
        newLeft = coordinates.left + 25;  //33
        newTop = coordinates.top + 25;    //44

        $(target).toggle(); // Move this line from last to here, before setting the offset

        $(target).offset({ top: newTop, left: newLeft });

    }
```

This is your solution, move target-toggle above setting of offset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why, but if you move the `$(target).toggle()` statement above the `$(target).offset()` statement, it will work as expected.